# Qqlite + HTML5 colocar os resultados em variáveis

Tags: javascript, html, html5, sqlite

E estou fazendo uma consulta em um banco Sqlite e queria que o resultado fosse armazenado em uma variável javascript para eu poder trabalhar com esses resultados no restante do código.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
db.transaction(function(tx) {
var ide = 1;

tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM tab_users', [ide], function (tx, results) {
var len = results.rows.length, i;

     for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       var_name = results.rows.item(i).name;
       var_country = results.rows.item(i).country;
     }

});
});
alert ("Name is " + var_name + " and country is " + var_country);
```

Mas esse código não funciona.. somente se eu colocar o `alert` dentro do `loop` desse jeito:

```
for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
   var_name = results.rows.item(i).name;
   var_country = results.rows.item(i).country;

   alert ("Name is " + var_name + " and country is " + var_country);

}
```

Eu preciso dessas variáveis pra usar no final do meu código html 
Alguém tem alguma sugestão de como vou conseguir fazer isso?

Comment: Se você colocar o alert FORA do for(), só vai exibir o último valor retornado do banco.

Comment: No caso dessa consulta só exibe um resultado mesmo, mas se eu colocar fora do fora do `db.transaction(function(tx) {` não exibe nada mesmo

Comment: O que você quer fazer? Quer trabalhar com TODOS os registros que voltam?

Comment: Só vai voltar um registro... quero trabalhar somente com ele

Comment: Tenta assim results.rows.item(0).name;

Comment: Deu o mesmo o erro.. no console apareceu: `Uncaught ReferenceError: var_name is not defined`

Comment: Agora entendi, CRIA as variavies  var_name e var_country Fora do FOR

Comment: Fiz como você falou.. (na verdade já tinha feito) Tentei criei elas fora do for.. mas também não funcionou... :(

Comment: Talvez o @Marcelo Bonifazio possa te ajudar.